# jmeter font size within dialog box

Tags: jmeter

I have tried all font sizes for jmeter and read all postings and currently I have the following in my system properties

```
jmeter.hidpi.mode=true
jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor=2.0
jmeter.toolbar.icons.size=32x32
jmeter.tree.icons.size=24x24
jsyntaxtextarea.font.family=28

jsyntaxtextarea.font.size=20
```

it seems to be ok in UI and tool bar however I can not get the attached area size larger I am not sure what to call it but it is very hard to read, how can I enlarge this area marked with blue attached pic.

[image]